# How to get datas with multiple variables in path with jekyll and liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

At its most basic level I need to append a partial object path onto an existing object path. In this particular instance I can't use plugins.

Say you have an object path:

```
{{ site.data.grants.2015.Return.ReturnHeader.ReturnTypeCd }}
```

Which, of course, can also be referenced as follows:

```
{% assign var = "ReturnTypeCd" %}
{{ site.data.grants.2015.Return.ReturnHeader[var] }}
```

How would I go about adding additional levels of nesting to the variable?

```
{% assign xTest = "Return.ReturnHeader.ReturnTypeCd" %}
{{ site.data.grants.2015[xTest] }} 

//does not work
```

I've played around with both dot and bracket notations and using `append` as well as `capture`, but can't seem to find a solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

This works :

Data file is `_data/grants.yml`

```
"2015":
  Return:
    ReturnHeader:
      ReturnTypeCd: "Et hop !"
```

Getting deep target with a "dotted" string :

```
{% assign dataPath = site.data.grants.2015 %}
{% assign target = "Return.ReturnHeader.ReturnTypeCd" %}

{% comment %} ++++ Transform target string to an array  {% endcomment %}
{% assign labels = target | split:"." %}

{% comment %} ++++
Looping in labels array and reassigning dataPath on each loop.
This goes deeper and deeper in the data tree
++++ {% endcomment %}

{% for label in labels %}
  <h2>Label : {{ label }}</h2>
  {% assign dataPath = dataPath[label] %}
  <p>dataPath : {{ dataPath }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```